# App to create local barcode database for fast packaging

Tags: android, barcode, package-manager

I have 1000 same items, with barcoded serial numbers. And a thousand boxes from them. Now i need to package each item to its own box (only by matching barcodes serial numbers). All items and boxes are visually same, so it would be quite tricky to check it with eyes: 1000 codes for each of 1000 items would yield to 1 million (in worst case) of in-head comparisons.

So i believe some software solution for this typical situation should exist: I can sequentially scan 1000 boxes, and put them in order. Meanwhile scanner should create ordered dataset. Then when scanning items it should tell me "put currently scanning item in box #345". It is quite typical task and I believe alredy written software should exist.

I have searched app for android, but there are either JUST scaners, either some globally defined database of shop items. Also I failed to find application with possibility of creating local data sets. On PC there are low quality libraries, and 640px webcams: All of 3 webcams (i currently have by hand) were uncapable to recognize Code39 with ZBar app `zbarcam`

I would ask for your experience(if you managed to work with codes): What could i use for my package managing means?

Comment: It's not for everyday use, just one time task. So i am looking for simple solution, without buying expensive specialized scanner and licensing complex software solutions for business.

Comment: Maybe my list of [Inventory apps with barcode support](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_barcode_inventory) could help you out?

Comment: Depending on how you value your time it might be quicker to aim for a workflow of pick up an item, scan it, start printing a new bar code label, put it in the first available box, attach the label over the original bar code. bar code printers are quiet reasonably priced and can be reused for other processes later. This will not require the huge work area required to sort 1000 boxes and the huge risk of putting the item in box #344 or #346 plus the physical effort & time will be a lot lower.